# How do I remove a package repository in DNF

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I'm not entirely confident this is the right term for this but a while ago I installed vscodium to my system, to do this I had to add another repository which dnf pulled from. I then removed vscodium but whenever I type `dnf update` it takes a moment pulling from `download.vscodium.com` how can I remove this repository so it doesn't need to do this when I use the update command?

In case it's important I use Fedora 36

Answer (score 1):

Repositories are represented by files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`; find the file pointing to `vscodium.com` there, and delete it.

```
grep -rl vscodium /etc/yum.repos.d
```

will tell you which file to delete. (Before you do so, check it to make sure it’s only defining a single repository.)

Comment: Thanks, I found the file but it won't let me delete it

Comment: You need to do so as root (`sudo rm …`).

Comment: @CriticalBackend Make sure that you are deleting it as root. You can also just disable the repository which can be done via the command line.